# Degree characterization

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I have been asked in a programming contest if it is possible to construct a graph just with the degree numbers. For example, given $1,2$ the answer would be no by the handshake lemma, but that's a sufficient condition, not a necessary condition. The question is: there is any way to answer this in polynomial time?

Thanks

Comment: It is called [Graph realization problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_realization_problem).

Comment: Thanks Ante, i am looking at it. :)